# Query the point only if it exist

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to see the information as JSON when I click on the feature. My features are many point rendered as cluster. With the code below I can query the point only if it is not into a cluster:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
   const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature
   })
    clusterSize = feature.get('features').length;
    if (clusterSize === 1) {
      if (feature) {
        json = feature.getProperties().features[0].values_;

        console.log(json);
      }
    }
})
```

When I click on any other area of my map I see thi error:

> Uncaught TypeError: feature is undefined

My aim is do something like this pseudo-code:

`if (feature != 0) { query point } else { do nothing }`

For me is not clear how I can do this; my JavaScript's skills aren't strong

Comment: before you set `clusterSize ` just do `if (!feature) return;`

Comment: I have the same error message @RenéDatenschutz

Comment: When there are more than one features each feature in `feature.get('features')` will have its own set of properties

Comment: Can you are more explicit please? @Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
   const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature
   })
   if (feature) {
     clusterSize = feature.get('features').length;
     if (clusterSize === 1) {
       json = feature.getProperties().features[0].values_;

       console.log(json);
     }
   }
})
```

Now if I click on the unclustered point I can get the properties, but if I click on the rest of the map there aren't errors.

Answer (score 0):

`feature.get('features')` is an array of the features in the cluster.  To get the properties of all the features you will need to read each one into an array

```
json = [];
feature.get('features').forEach(function(feature){
  json.push(feature.getProperties());
});
console.log(json);
```

If you have both clusters and normal features on your map you will need

```
   const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature) {
     return feature
   })
   if (feature) {
     const features = feature.get('features');
     if (features) {
       // this is a cluster
       ...
     } else {
       // not a cluster
       json = feature.getProperties()
     }
   }
```

Comment: But I don't need to get all properties, I need to have only the properties from the unclusetered single point. With my code I can do that if I click on the unclustered point, but if I click on the rest of the map(not on the cluster or on the single point) I see the error above. This is not a blocking error but there is. I can use my map without problem but I know that if someone inspect my map he can see the error.